# Selenium Grid : Unable to access Hub url/console through browser client

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, grid, webdriver, selenium-grid

I follwed steps  to start selenium hub as below. to start selenium grid hub

1. hub.json file :

   ```
   {
   "port": 4441,
   "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
   "custom": {},
   "capabilityMatcher":"org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
   "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
   "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
   "role": "hub",
   "debug": false,
   "browserTimeout": 0,
   "timeout": 1800
    }
   ```
2. I fired command :

   ```
   java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=E:\SELENIUM_DOWNLOADS\Drivers\chromedriver.exe -jar E:\SELENIUM_DOWNLOADS\Jars\selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub.json
   ```
3. Result :

   ```
   E:\>cd \selenium_practice\Maven_Workspace\DataDriven_zoho_18April2019_GRID
   E:\selenium_practice\Maven_Workspace\DataDriven_zoho_18April2019_GRID>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=E:\SELENIUM_DOWNLOADS\Drivers\chromedriver.exe -jar E:\SELENIUM_DOWNLOADS\Jars\selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub.json
   00:40:48.652 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3'
   00:40:48.652 INFO [GridLauncherV3$2.launch] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4441
   2018-04-22 00:40:49.166:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1081ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
   00:40:49.572 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running 
   00:40:49.572 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://192.168.1.10:4441/grid/register/
   00:40:49.572 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://192.168.1.10:4441/wd/hub
   ```
4. When i entered browser http://192.168.1.10:4441/grid/register/

   ```
   HTTP ERROR 500
   Problem accessing /grid/register. Reason:
   Server Error
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null
   ```

Comment: Can you update the question with the _Selenium Grid hub_ startup trace logs?

Comment: i have already updated grid logg in point no:3

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things which you need to consider while initiating the *Selenium Grid Hub* through customized configuration as follows :

- Your **hub.json** file looks pretty perfect.
- While starting the *Selenium Grid Hub* you can remove the argument **-Dwebdriver** as follows :

  ```
  java -jar E:\SELENIUM_DOWNLOADS\Jars\selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub.json
  ```
- You need to access the *Selenium Grid Hub Console* through the url :

  ```
  http://localhost:4441/grid/console
  ```
- To view the configuration you need to access the url :

  ```
  http://localhost:4441/grid/console?config=true&configDebug=true
  ```
- Snapshot of the *Selenium Grid Hub Console* configuration as per your **hub.json** file :

[image: HubConfig]

Comment: Thanks , but when i try to  run  on other machine  by command

Comment: What ? What happens? Error?